# Simple L -system in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, iteration, l-systems

Hello I'm looking for a way to implement a simple L-system into function in python which would take three arguments : axiom , rules and number of interations(if iterations = 0 output would be previously input axiom). I came up with some code it only works on 1 iteration and I dont know how to implement more.

The code I came up with :

```
#  x = axiom
#  y = rules
#  z would be iterations which I dont know how to implement

def lsystem(x,y):
    output = ''
    for i in x:
        if i in y:
            output += y[i]
        else:
            output += i
    print(output)

rules = { "A" : "ABA" , "B" : "BBB"}
# output    lsystem("AB",rules) ---> ABABBB
```

Comment: What is the problem of your code ? You only wish to know how to implement the `z` parameter ? How would it need to be implemented : If z is 0, if z is superior to the number of iteration in x, etc...

Comment: Yes I want want to know how to implement z  parameter, I think it should be implemented as some kind of loop. And the steps for z =2 would look like this  output =AB - - - > output =ABABBB - - - - > output ABABBBABABBBBBBBBB

Comment: Keep me up to date if my answer fits your needs. ;)

Comment: Works as intended . Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the given `axioms` if `iterations == 0`. In this function, you return the argument `axioms` you've been given, so that if `iterations == 0`, you will return the given, untouched axioms.

Then, later on, at the end of your `iteration`, if `iteration` there is, the newly created axioms you get from the `iteration` is transfered into `axioms` so that you will return the good value, and if need be, the next `iteration` will have the newly created axioms to iterate on. :)

```
def lsystem(axioms, rules, iterations):
    #    We iterate through our method required numbers of time.
    for _ in range(iterations):
        #    Our newly created axioms from this iteration.
        newAxioms = ''

        #    This is your code, but with renamed variables, for clearer code.
        for axiom in axioms:
            if axiom in rules:
                newAxioms += rules[axiom]
            else:
                newAxioms += axiom
        #    You will need to iterate through your newAxioms next time, so...
        #    We transfer newAxioms, to axioms that is being iterated on, in the for loop.
        axioms = newAxioms
    return axioms

rules = { "A" : "ABA" , "B" : "BBB"}
print(lsystem('AB', rules, 0))
# outputs : 'AB'

print(lsystem('AB', rules, 1))
# outputs : 'ABABBB'

print(lsystem('AB', rules, 2))
# outputs : 'ABABBBABABBBBBBBBB'
```

Comment: I don't think this code is correct.



If we set the rules as :
Rules : (A->A+B, B->A-B)

The Result at N=3 should be :
A+B+A-B+A+B-A+B

But the answer here is :
A+B+A-B+A+B-A-B